# In Java, how to achieve this type of number rounding?

Tags: java, decimal, rounding

I am writing a small physics app. What I am planning to do is to make number rounding. The issue is that it is not a fixed rounding, but rather a variable rounding that depends on the value of the decimal digits. I will give an explanation for the issue.

- I always need to keep the whole integer part (if any) and the first five decimal digits (if any).
- half up rounding is always used.

  21.1521421056 becomes 21.15214
  34.1521451056 becomes 34.15215
- If the result consists of only decimal digits then:

  - If the first five digits include non zero digits then keep them.

    0.52131125 becomes 0.52131
    0.21546874 becomes 0.21547
    0.00120012 becomes 0.0012
  - If the first five digits are all zero digits 0.00000 then go down to first five digits that include non zero digits.

    0.0000051234 becomes 0.0000051234
    0.000000000000120006130031 becomes 0.00000000000012001

I need to play this rounding while working with `BigDecimal` because it is a requirement for my needs.

Comment: It seems like you will have to do it manually (writing your own code), I don't think there is a method to do this specific kind of rounding (but I may be wrong).

Comment: I agree that it is odd enough so that you have to do some coding... but `BigDecimal` is a good base for it; just set the scale to what you need based in the values.

Comment: @Cruncher if >4 places right of the first non-zero> is consistent with my explanation; the first five digits (after the point) that include non zero digits. then it is OK.

Comment: Read this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this will work, based on experimentation, if I understand correctly what you want.  If `d` is a `BigDecimal` that contains the number:

```
BigDecimal rounded = d.round(new MathContext
    (d.scale() - d.precision() < 5 
        ? d.precision() - d.scale() + 5 
        : 5));
```

Comment: Wow, I can't believe this works. Please provide an explanation to make this a good answer. Especially since the documentation on `scale()` and `precision()` are less than perfect.

Comment: @Cruncher I don't understand those methods either.  I just dumped the output for various values of the `new MathContext` parameter and figured out which one would make it work and what the formula would look like.

Comment: It looks to me at first glance that they are probably used in the internal implementation of BigDecimal, and the authors decided that they may as well supply it as public api. And didn't decide to write decent documentation. (unscaledValue is defined by scale, and scale is defined by unscaledValue)

Answer (score -2):

Is this, what you are looking for?

```
public static void main(String[] args){
     double d = 0.000000000000120006130031;

     System.out.println(round(d, 5));
 }

 private static double round(double d, int precision) {
    double factor = Math.pow(10D, precision);
    int value = (int)d;
    double re = d-value;


    if (re * factor <= 0.1 && d != 0) {
        while (re * factor <= 0.1) {
            factor *= 10;
        }
        factor *= Math.pow(10D, precision);
    }
    re = ((int)(re*factor))/factor+value;

    return re;
}
```

(sorry, it's a little quick & dirty, but you can improve it, if you want)

EDIT: 
make it `<=` in the conditions, this should work better

Comment: The OP explicitly stated he needs to work with `BigDecimal`, not `float`

Comment: @JimGarrison There are several methods to multiply and divide BigDecimals, so it should be easy to refactor the code for his needs. Further reading: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#multiply(java.math.BigDecimal)